# Get total number of records being processed by trigger in transaction

Tags: apex, trigger

In my trigger I want to prevent something happening if the total number of records in a transaction is 500 (because it's breaking).

Trigger.size returns the number of records in that current 'chunk', so if I process 500 records in total it returns 200, 200, 100.

Is there any method to allow me to check the total number of records in the transaction?

Comment: Each chunk should count as a single transaction - does it give you the same errors if you only process 200 records? I'm guessing you're importing data with the import wizard, or perhaps running a batch class job?

Comment: No... I don't think so - if you've got 800 records salesforce automatically chunks them up into 4 lots of 200 and runs the trigger 4 times, but it's all within the same transaction... i believe? If you're doing a batch job each of the batches would be a new transaction, but I'm just looking at running an update using anonymous apex.

Comment: Governor limits will be reset for each trigger invocation while processing the records in chunk. So, for 800 records to be processed, trigger invocation occurs 4 times (each time processing 200 records) and the governor limits are reset for each of these. So, you could consider them as single transactions.

Comment: oh ok! many thanks. It doesn't actually matter for my issue because my underlying problem is actually having too many loop iterations in a flow that runs off the trigger.

Comment: @arut just did a little test and it doesn't seem to me like the gov limits are reset if we're talking about anonymous apex - if I make a trigger with 90 SOQL queries in it and process 500 records, I get through the first chunk and then the second chunk hits the governor limit which suggests to me that it isn't reset.

Comment: @arut That is not true. If you DML 800 records, the corresponding 4 trigger chunks count  as a single, combined transaction (rather than individual transactions).

Comment: @DerekF Thanks for correcting my poor choice of words. It is indeed a single combined transaction (with only the context variables & governor limits reset for each invocation?)

Comment: @arut Still not quite. The governor limits are not reset between each trigger chunk.

Comment: @eaeaoo Sorry about the incorrect statement made earlier.

Comment: @DerekF Appreciate the response. I did a quick test and found that limits were not reset.

Comment: @DerekF So, looking at `If a Bulk API request causes a trigger to fire multiple times for chunks of 200 records, governor limits are reset between these trigger invocations for the same HTTP request.` (from https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_static.htm?search_text=reset). I basically mis-interpreted this statement earlier. When I invoke 800 DML via bulk api, would each chunk be consider as part of separate trigger transaction or part of single combined transaction? Limits are reset for each chunk, but documentation is not clear abt transaction

Comment: @arut That sounds like a good candidate for a separate question of your own.

Comment: Yeah....I thought of posting it as a separate question, but just want to check. Will post it as a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The closest we can get to that right now is to use `Limits.getDMLRows();`

A while back when I was testing out various methods of figuring out how to detect when records are automatically being re-tried (as part of an AllOrNone = false transaction), I noticed that the DML row limit is not updated with each trigger chunk.

I.e. If you note the current value of `Limits.getDMLRows()`, then perform some DML on 1234 records, each of the 7 trigger chunks will display (current + 1234) when you check the limit inside the trigger that is run when that DML is executed.

If you can guarantee that your trigger is the first trigger executed in a given transaction, or have some way to ensure that `Limits.getDMLRows()` is executed before any DML operation you have control over, then you can figure out the total number of records being DML'd.

Answer (score 2):

You can't directly identify if this is a multi-part transaction, or how many records have been submitted in total. You would need to somehow arrange for this in your code, such as disabling the trigger through a static variable if the size would be too large.